# Android passing image to a ListView containing an ImageView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

I'm creating a ListView that contains two TextViews and an ImageView.

I'm passing data to my SimpleAdapter using a Hashmap, so I convert the ids of the images to a string and then later in the SimpleAdapter I convert them back to integers to set the image resource.

However that doesn't seem to work.

The relevant code is:

The oncreate of my activity

```
clubImages = new Integer[] {
    R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2,
    R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4,
    R.drawable.pic5                
};

ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

// create the grid item mapping
String[] from = new String[] {"image"};
int[] to = new int[] {R.id.club_image};

// prepare the list of all records
List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
for(int i = 0; i < eventTitles.length; i++){
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("image", getString(clubImages[i]));
    fillMaps.add(map);
}

// fill in the grid_item layout
SimpleAdapter adapter = new MySimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.eventview_row, from, to);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the simpleadapter class

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> results;

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.results = data;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){

        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/aircruiser.ttf");
        View v = view;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.eventview_row, null);
        }

        mClubImageImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.club_image);        

        int ClubImageHelper = Integer.parseInt(results.get(position).get("image").toString());
        mClubImageImageView.setImageResource(ClubImageHelper);

        return v;
    }
}
```

The error in my logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime(19406): java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'res/drawable-hdpi/pic1.png' as integer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass `R.drawable.pic1` as a `String` and then parse it back as an `Integer`. This will not work, instead simply pass the initial `Integer` drawable ids directly in the `HashMap`:

```
List<HashMap<String, Integer>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < eventTitles.length; i++){
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        map.put("image", clubImages[i]);
        fillMaps.add(map);
    }
```

I hope I understand what you want. You could make a class to hold the data that you want to pass in to the adapter, for example:

```
class DataObject {
   int imageId;
   String firstString;
   String secondString; // add here any string that you want to put in your list

   public DataObject(String firstString, String secondString, int imageId) {
       this.imageId = imageId;
       this.firstString = firstString;
       this.secondString = secondString;
   }
}
```

Then construct the list for the adapter:

```
List<HashMap<String, DataObject>> fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, DataObject>>();
    for(int i = 0; i < eventTitles.length; i++){
        HashMap<String, DataObject> map = new HashMap<String, DataObject>();

        map.put("image", new DataObject("First String", "second String", clubImages[i]));
        fillMaps.add(map);
    }
```

In the `getView()` method retrieve the `DataObject` and use its content data as you please.

Comment: The problem is that I have to pass 2 strings too, I left them out of the code as it seemed irrelevant. Is there a way to pass a List<HashMap<String, Integer>> and a List<HashMap<String, String>> to the SimpleAdapter?

Comment: @MatsRaemen I've edited my answer, I hope that this is what you want.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, but I can't figure out how to get the calues from the DataObject in the getView() method. If for example I have a TextView mEventTitleTextView and want to set the text of that TextView to the value of "First String", how should I do that? mEventTitleTextView.setText(results.get(position).get("First String")); wasn't a great succes

Comment: @MatsRaemen If you use the String `"image"`(like in your code) in the `HashMap` then do: `mEventTitleTextView.setText(results.get(position).get("image").firstString);`

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html)  is an good example that may help you

[image]