# How to transfer image from one activity to another activity of listview in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I have an expandablelistview that contains groupview and childview. I am getting the values for childview from rows added in nextactivity. But now the problem is I want to transfer the image from rows(I am getting the textview values from the same, but want to get the imageview) added in nextactivity to previousactivity. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055994/android-passing-image-to-a-listview-containing-an-imageview

Comment: Thank you Aerrow.. I will try that solution..